# How to easily implement "who is online" in Grails or Java Application?

Tags: java, grails, grails-plugin, shiro

I am building a community website in grails (using Apache Shiro for security and authentication system) and I would like to implement the feature "who is online?".

This url http://cksource.com/forums/viewonline.php (see snapshot below if you do not have acess to this Url) gives an example of what I would like to achieve.

How can I do that in the most simple way? Is there any existing solution in Grails or in Java ?

Thank you.

Snapshot : [Snapshot of Who is online page http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.2de8468a86.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.2de8468a86.png) or see here : http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?2de8468a86.png

Comment: This URL requires a login, so it's useless for anyone who isn't or won't register on that site.

Comment: @BalusC Question updated

Answer (score 23):

You need to collect all logged in users in a `Set<User>` in the **application** scope. Just hook on `login` and `logout` and add and remove the `User` accordingly. Basically:

```
public void login(User user) {
    // Do your business thing and then
    logins.add(user);
}

public void logout(User user) {
    // Do your business thing and then
    logins.remove(user);
}
```

If you're storing the logged-in users in the session, then you'd like to add another hook on session destroy to issue a logout on any logged-in user. I am not sure about how Grails fits in the picture, but talking in Java Servlet API, you'd like to use [`HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29) for this.

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    User user = (User) event.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    if (user != null) {
        Set<User> logins = (Set<User>) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
        logins.remove(user);
    }
}
```

You can also just let the `User` model implement [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html). The implemented methods will be invoked automagically whenever the `User` instance is been put in session or removed from it (which would also happen on session destroy).

```
public class User implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        Set<User> logins = (Set<User>) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
        logins.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        Set<User> logins = (Set<User>) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
        logins.remove(this);
    }

    // @Override equals() and hashCode() as well!

}
```

Comment: Perhaps also add a lease and refresh it upon user actions in order to filter out inactive sessions without proper logout.

Comment: What if users don't logout explicitly but just close their browser?

Comment: @Partly and @Burt: just hooking on servletcontainer-managed session destroy as described in the last paragraph is sufficient.

Comment: @BalusC. Thank you for your answer. However, this will not work for  returning users that have enabled the "Remember me" cookie, right ?

Comment: @fabien: this will work. The "remember me" cookie doesn't rely on the session. The "remember me" logic usually checks the presence of both the long-living cookie and the logged in `User` and if the `User` is absent, then it will invoke the login (putting in session). You just hook (listen) on whatever method/approach it is using to login the `User`.

Comment: @BalusC. I'll try your solution and update this thread on the results. Thank you very much.

Comment: This solution doesn't work across server restarts if the web server is serializing and restoring sessions. Still looking for a workaround to this.

Comment: @BalusC If I go with the first approach, with HttpSessionListener, at what point do I set the "logins" attribute in the session?

Comment: @madness: It's not set in session scope, it's set in application scope. Look, it's an attribute of `ServletContext`. Just do it during application init in some `ServletContextListener`, or manually when it's absent. Or, when you're using CDI, just use an `@ApplicationScoped` bean.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed some time ago on the mailing list: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Information-about-all-logged-in-users-with-Acegi-or-SpringSecurity-in-Grails-td1372911.html

Comment: Thank you Stefan. However the thread you are pointing is about Spring Security and unfortunately I am using Shiro.

Comment: Hi Fabien, I did not read that carefully enough - the link I've posted just works for acegi.