# Main list of all the user logged-in in a struts application

Tags: session, logging, struts2, admin

In my struts2 application, in the login action I am placing the user and role in the session.

I want to keep track of all the users who logged in so as to do stuff like following :

1. Avoid multiple login of same user-id.
2. Check wheather a user is looged in or not ! Or any body with role Admin is logged in or not !
3. and in some other actions !

How to do it any suggestion!

And also how to maintain the issues like

- User close browser without loggin !  etc

Any material with more information of session can also realy help !

Comment: I think what you need is application scope instead of session scope variable. Session is user based while application scope variable is shared across the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a column in you user table called `logged_in_time` (`timestamp` type) and update it with the time when user logs in and make it null when user logs out.

- **Avoid multiple login of same user-id:** : check if this columns alreadt has some value or not.
- **Check whether a user is looged in or not** : check if that column is null or not.
- **User close browser without logging out** : A schduler job may be, that runs at fixed interval of time to check the session(using sessionid may be) of the user and update this field accordingly.

Take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771103/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-httpsession-objects-in-a-web-application) for further information. And [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963174/absolute-session-expiration-after-n-minutes-even-if-user-is-using-the-system).