# How to access tomcat session context?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

I'm using tomcat8 and I like to look through the available sessions and invalidate/alter some sessions in my servlet
Currently I keep every sessions in my own context(Vector) and I believe it's not a good idea.
So how may I access tomcat session management/context to do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think your looking for `HttpSessionListener`.You can hold of sessions all with help of this. Thats the most cleaner way i can think of.

See below examples

[How to easily implement "who is online" in Grails or Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271676/how-to-easily-implement-who-is-online-in-grails-or-java-application/3271748#3271748)

[How can i load Java HttpSession from JSESSIONID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092363/how-can-i-load-java-httpsession-from-jsessionid/3092495#3092495)

Comment: So this is the exact thing I'm doing right now dear, I keep tracking of the sessions again(beside tomcat does) somewhere. the `HttpSessionListener` is kinda event guy, I want to access the sessions without any specific event sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMX to look into Tomcat's internals, including the current list of sessions. Use `jvisualvm` to connect to a running Tomcat and look-around for the interesting data.

Then use the JMX API to connect to the (in-process) JMX server from your application and find the (Session) `Manager` bean to get everything.